# Making subsections in network-dataset for using location allocation in ArcMap?

Tags: web-service, location-allocation, enumeration-areas

I'm making a simple smart grid model on ArcGIS for my thesis and I have a town surrounded by several renewable energy sources from all around. I want to divide the network dataset into four subsections so certain energy sources supply certain subsections (which will each have a demand point). I'm using ArcGIS (ArcMap).